# SharePoint 2013 - User can't access site(s)

Tags: 2013, user, access, denied

I have a user who left our organization couple years ago, and now has returned. during that time, her account, domain/exchange etc. was probably deleted with our procedures.

User has returned, and can connect with SharePoint online, exchange.. but when it comes with our old 2013 on-premises SharePoint, gets denied access etc. I looked at couple of the subsites and see the user as added to owners group in corresponding sites. but can't access them, also everyone group access site we have, the user can't even access those.

Any suggestions where I should troubleshoot? I tried add/delete re-add to different groups in case there was inheritance issue, but if user couldn't access open view/read sites.. it might be something else.

I just noticed too in the site collection, hub.site.com/_layouts/15/people.aspx, the user is not listed there. but when I got add the user to subsites etc. the user name comes up and is added to the owners group.

Comment: Try to delete the user from userprofiles and do a full sync.